# wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan

Tags: networking, kernel, network-manager, scanner, intel-wireless

I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts with gnome, I connect normally to wifi of my house, but in my college i can't, my colleges wifi is an open wifi with a html login page. My notebook is a dell Inspiron 14.
I run in terminal

`tailf /var/log/syslog`

and appeared

```
Sep  5 17:42:41 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:42:42 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Sep  5 17:43:04 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:43:44 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:43:47 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Sep  5 17:44:47 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:44:48 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Sep  5 17:45:50 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:45:52 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Sep  5 17:46:24 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:46:53 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Sep  5 17:46:54 junkiegoat wpa_supplicant[949]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

I installed wicd and nothing happended.If someone can help me I appreciate.

Comment: What happens when you try to run wicd?

Answer (score 2):

Typically this problem is caused when the wpa_supplicant can't scan the configured ESSID.  The top reasons for this are that the region/country code are not configured and my personal favourite one is when I miss-spell my ESSID.